# Accessing inetmgr from Run Window

Tags: windows-8

while i am trying to open inetmgr for IIS through Run window displaying message like window cannot open inetmgr make sure name correctly,but in start menu i am getting IIS option

what would be the problem with RUN Window search

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage IIS sites you need to install the "IIS Management Console" feature by going to `Control Panel` > `Programs and Features` > `Turn Windows Features On Or Off`.

Expand `Internet Information Services` > `Web Management Tools` and select `IIS Management Console`

[image]

When this has installed, you should be able to use:
`C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe` OR just `inetmgr`
[image]

While these screenshots show Windows 10 - I have done the same before numerous times on 8/8.1 as indicated in your question.

Comment: i enabled that one also but not getting through inetmgr

Comment: i am getting IIS window through C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\InetMgr.exe  but when   i tried to access localhost in url its getting like unable to connect and not shown in even installed program also so could u tell how to reinstall IIS ,but already i tried to install by checked IIS in the turnwindows updates on/off  there no result